# Swift3 - Issue with extending type Collection

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, protocols, swift-playground

Good day,

Im trying to understand protocols and extensions in Swift 3.

Im trying to extend `Collection` by a mutable functions to e.g. heal all enemies inside an Array of Type `Enemy`.

Here is an example GIST: https://gist.github.com/flowinho/5985928f803d902b75fc69ee9ce26537

Im still new to the field of adding mutable functions by extending protocols, so i dont understand why LOC 75 of that gist doesn't increase the amount of HP of all enemies.

What am i doing wrong?
How to fix this?

Best wishes and have wonderful day,

Flowinho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because struct is a value type and a copy is made when you assign it. Your code will work if you use classes instead of structs. Or you need to access the array elements by index:

```
for item in myStructArray {
    // changes copy of item, array is not altered
    item.property = newValue
}

for i in 0..<myStructArray.count {
    // this does what you need, changes the struct in the array
    myStructArray[i].property = newValue
}
```

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot that structs are passed by value. Thank you.

Comment: no problem :) please accept the answer if it helped :)